# How to search a contact's phone number? (Abaddressbook)

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

In my iOS app, I want to find the phone number of the contact that matches the name.

```
CFErrorRef *error = NULL;

// Create a address book instance.
ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);

// Get all people's info of the local contacts.
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressbook);
CFIndex numPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressbook);
for (int i=0; i < numPeople; i++) {

    // Get the person of the ith contact.
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
    ## how do i compare the name with each person object?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the person's name with `ABRecordCopyCompositeName`, and test if the search string is contained in the name with `CFStringFind`.

For example, to find contacts with "Appleseed" in his name:

```
CFStringRef contactToFind = CFSTR("Appleseed");

CFErrorRef *error = NULL;

// Create a address book instance.
ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);

// Get all people's info of the local contacts.
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressbook);
CFIndex numPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressbook);
for (int i=0; i < numPeople; i++) {

    // Get the person of the ith contact.
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

    // Get the composite name of the person
    CFStringRef name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);

    // Test if the name contains the contactToFind string
    CFRange range = CFStringFind(name, contactToFind, kCFCompareCaseInsensitive);

    if (range.location != kCFNotFound)
    {
        // Bingo! You found the contact
        CFStringRef message = CFStringCreateWithFormat(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, CFSTR("Found: %@"), name);
        CFShow(message);
        CFRelease(message);
    }

    CFRelease(name);
}

CFRelease(allPeople);
CFRelease(addressbook);
```

Hope this helps. Although your question was asked 5 months ago...